# React Native Navigation Bottom tab navigator only clickable on the edges

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have an issue where only the left and right buttons in my bottom tab navigator are clickable, and  even then only at the extreme side.

When I inspect the touchable areas, it appears that the entire area is touchable.

This problem has happened intermittently throughout the process of coding this app, and I can't tell why it's happening.

I've attached an image which shows that the touchable area is correct according to the inspector, and my View above the bottom tab navigator doesn't seem to be overlapping with it.

[image]

The bottom tab navigator code is below:

```
const TabsScreen = () => (
<Tabs.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
        tabBarLabelStyle: { fontSize: 12, paddingBottom: 5 },
        tabBarStyle: { marginBottom: Platform.OS === "ios" ? -15 : 0 }
    }}
>
    <Tabs.Screen
        options={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarActiveTintColor: 'black',
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: "#9e9e9e",
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
                <FontAwesome5 name="tasks" size={24} color={focused ? 'black' : "#9e9e9e"} />
            ),
        }}
        name="Tasks"
        component={Home}
    />
    <Tabs.Screen
        options={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarActiveTintColor: 'black',
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: "#9e9e9e",
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
                <Feather name="archive" size={24} color={focused ? 'black' : "#9e9e9e"} />
            ),
        }}
        name="Archive"
        component={Archive}
    />
    <Tabs.Screen
        options={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarActiveTintColor: 'black',
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: "#9e9e9e",
            tabBarBadge: BadgeNotification() === true ? <Text style={{ fontSize: 10 }}></Text> : null,
            tabBarBadgeStyle: { backgroundColor: '#00a152' },


            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="bullseye-arrow" size={24} color={focused ? 'black' : "#9e9e9e"} />),
        }}
        name="Productivity"
        component={Streak}
    />
</Tabs.Navigator>
)
```

The styling for the view above the tab navigator is:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  },
```

This happens on every page. Hoping someone else has faced this issue before.

Comment: I just turned off remote debugging and it now works. It also works in production build.

Any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7883 Seems like this is a known issue